# How do I get the HD recovery icon back on my mac?

Tags: mac, partitioning, boot-camp, hard-drive-recovery

I partitioned my mac air to be able to use as windows and as a mac. One day prompted my windows partition did not have enough memory. I dont know what I did but now boot camp can not be found and when I try to restart macios is not an option. Recovery HD is not an option because I just want to put back to factory settings and take back to just being a mac. I have tried everything. Help

Answer (score 1):

If the internal Recovery cannot be found, suspect disk damage or failure. It should automatically start Internet Recovery if it can't find a Recovery volume locally.

To trigger Internet Recovery manually, hold Cmd/opt/R at the chimes on boot.
Use Disk Utility [View menu > Show All Devices] to Erase the entire drive, then reinstall macOS.

This is *destructive*. You will need to migrate back from Time Machine afterwards.

If no drive except the temporary Recovery startup drive can be seen [which is held in RAM, not on disk], disk failure is most likely.